# Auto generate id in child table when value insert in parent table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two table which is the parent and the child table. Now I insert a value to the parent table, with auto increment id. The code is something like this:

```
string query2 = "INSERT INTO printer_info(printer_ip) VALUES(@ipAddress)";
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query2, connection);

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ipAddress", pAddress);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now my problem is that when the value insert in the parent table. How if I want the id in the child table to be generated automatically?Please advise.

```
   ID | printer_ip               printer_id | page_count
   ---------------    ------>    -----------------------
    1 | 10.0.0.0                            |

   PRIMARY KEY ID                FOREIGN KEY printer_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert a row in child too, just after parent row is created, then you can make use of `last_insert_id()` in the next insert statement.

**Example**:

```
string query2 = "INSERT INTO printer_info(printer_ip) VALUES(@ipAddress)";
MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(query2, connection);

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ipAddress", pAddress);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

string query_for_child_row = "INSERT INTO printer_queue(printer_id, page_count) 
                              VALUES( LAST_INSERT_ID(), @page_count )";
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand( query_for_child_row, connection );

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@page_count", page_count );
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: HINT: those two actions should be performed inside single transaction to avoid inconsistency in case one of them fails...

Comment: if we use the last insert id, it will insert id after the last insert id from the child table rite? Means it did not sync with the parent table. For ex. If id 1 in my parent table consist of 2 value count in the child table, the child printer_id cant be like 1,1 . It will be like 1,2 . Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: If new `parent_id` is `'1'` then, no matter where you called the function but, `'last_insert_id()'` would return the same `'1'`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [insert trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to add new row in child table when new row in parent table shows up.

**EDIT**

HINT: those two actions should be performed inside single transaction to avoid inconsistency in case one of them fails...